# find + regex + files with a pattern

Tags: regex, sed, find

How do I find 2 files that i want? `./test_jkl45.csv` and `./test_abc12.csv`

```
$ find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/*.csv"
./test_jkl45.csv
./test_def45.csv
./test_abc12.csv
./test_ghi12.csv
```

I have tried this but it returns nothing:

```
$ find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/*(jkl45)|(abc12).csv"
```

Can anyone clarify the error in my ways?

Comment: why not just `find . -name '*.csv'` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
find -regextype sed -regex '.*\(jkl45\|abc12\).*'
```

`sed` is using *basic posix regular expressions*. Check their documentation [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).

Comment: tks, can you explain that in laymans terms? does it need the `'` , as opposed to `"`, and ` \ `? how can I get that to work in this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iJ4gF4/1)?

Comment: this is the working [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iJ4gF4/2). I had to remove the ` \ `  - `.*(jkl45|abc12).*`, still a bit unclear.

Comment: As I told, `sed` is using *basic posix regular expressions*. Check the documentation I've linked. You are using *perl compatible regular expressions* (on regex101.com). That's like talking chinese to a japanese guy. He will not understand you.

Comment: why does this not work `find -regextype sed -regex ".*\t_(jkl45\|abc12\).*"
`? I want to add to the criteria...